# Is it possible to create a loop that calls a method every time it finishes executing?

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to create a loop that calls a method every time it finishes executing? I would like to continually call the same method every time it finishes executing.

I am a beginner and I have only seen loops that work every x time but I don't know if it is possible to do this.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using something like the following:

```
   fun loop(){
        var counter = 0
        var run = true
        
        while(run){
            counter++
            if(counter > 100)
                run = false
            
            // call method here
        }
    }
```

This will call a method 100 times. When you remove the run parameter, and place `while(true)`, the code will run infinitely. This is not recommended however.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use recursion. Recursion is often used to break down big problems to smaller ones calling the same method within it's body. Here is an example in kotlin

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {  
     val number = 5  
     val result: Long  
     result = factorial(number)  
     println("Factorial of $number = $result")  
} 


fun factorial(n: Int): Long {  
    return if(n == 1){  
          n.toLong()  
    }  
    else{  
        n*factorial(n-1)  
    }  
}
```

In this example we calculate the factorial of a given number with the recursive function. To break it down even more, it looks like this.

```
factorial(5)   
   factorial(4)   
      factorial(3)   
         factorial(2)   
            factorial(1)   
               return 1   
            return 2*1 = 2   
         return 3*2 = 6   
      return 4*6 = 24   
   return 5*24 = 120
```